# How do I create a record in firebase with a specific users credential?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a requirement of an app that has a contact form. I need to add records securely with the realtime database rules set to the uid of a specific user say my creds to prevent someone from adding records to the dB from anywhere but my form.
All the articles I looked talked about firebase in test mode with the rules set as read and write to true but doing so someone can have access to my dB and populate records from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Firebase documentation on [implementing content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access), which contains these rules for the Realtime Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To write to this database, the user would need to be signed in, and then:

```
firebase.database().ref('some_path').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set("hello world");
```

Comment: I had looked into this but not sure how do we achieve this in javascript. My understanding is first we will have to sign in with the content owner’s id which would set the auth.uid but how do we pass that uid while creating a record in the db.  Is there a way by which I can specify the uid of the content owner while creating the record.

Comment: @sud Are you trying to create an inbox for a particular user?

Comment: Once the user is signed in, their ID token is passed to Firebase automatically with every request, and `auth.uid` in the rules will be populated automatically.